# Can you clear up my punctuation syntactical doubt?

Tags: punctuation, commas, correlating-conjunctions

> Items to be worn at school:   kind of White 'V' neck shirt with white flaps with house stripes, white socks, white hair band and white shoes, House colour scarf.

I feel like the **and** should come between last two phrases as I have seen this standard at most of the phrases. Is the above construction correct and what is the logic behind not putting the **and** at between the last two?

On the side, I also noticed a capital 'H'. Might  it signify something?

Comment: There is no parenthesis here. The commas all separate list items.

Comment: The capital "H" signifies that "House" represents  the living accommodation  where the girls are in a boarding school.  "House stripes" should also have a capital "H", and the second sentence should read "House coloured scarf", though "House scarf" would also be appropriate, just as "House tie" would be appropriate for boys.

Answer (score 0):

Consider bulleted lists:

- There are a series of items
- A new line for each item
- There is a bullet or other symbol
- No "and" before the final item

What you have is a compressed bulleted list. To save space the writer has joined the items of the bulleted list into a single line. The effect isn't beautiful English, but it is functional. You are correct that a normal list in a paragraph has the last item joined with "and".

The capital "H" is a fault, as is the "W" of "White". It is quite common in a bulleted list to begin each item with a capital, even when the item isn't a full sentence. The writer has not changed the case to lowercase when writing the list in a paragraph. This should not be considered to be "good writing" or used as a model for your own texts.

Comment: I have seen sentences like- Keep us pure and kind and true. They could also be written as pure, kind and true?

Comment: -1 A "normal"  list does not require a comma: *We saw all three colors: red, white, blue.*

Comment: A list does require something to separate the elements. In speech this is a intonation group, in writing it is usually a comma. It is normal (but not required) to join the last item of a list with "and". Thus "red, white and blue" is correct as is "red, white, blue". But "red white blue" is mispunctuated; the comma is required.